# Does anyone know the CSS to put the outer border around textboxes like this from Twitter?

Tags: css

Does anyone know the CSS required to add an outer border around textboxes like this example from Twitter?

[image: Twitter Example]

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can open firebug/dev tools while on twitter, and inspect the element. You'll learn how they do it. It's really a great technique to learn new things. Try it out.

Comment: It's almost certainly a combination of two elements. Probably a `DIV` and an `INPUT` being styled.

Comment: If you also want to learn about how to do other things like Twitter, take a look at the bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapping div outside of the input box and give it that background color and rounded corners!

HTML:

```
<div class="outter"><input class="inputbox"></input></div>
```

CSS:

```
.outter {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inputbox {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Here you have a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsBgw/

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys... really appreciate it! Didn't think I needed a wrap around it but thats what I'll do... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

outline:

```
input{outline:solid 4px #ccc}
```

(another option it to wrap the input with div of course)

Answer (score 1):

```
.classname
{
box-shadow:0 0 2px red
}
```

use this class or you and add  box-shadow property to your existing class. You can increase 2px to 5px or 10 for broder shadow

Comment: Not sure where you're seeing a box shadow in his post?

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius:4px;
}
```

You'll want to cover the other border radius too, `-moz-` & `-webkit-`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BqpZh/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow) property

http://jsfiddle.net/VXJdV/

```
input {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
```

Comment: This did it: box-shadow : 0px 0px 0px 4px #e8ebee; - http://i3.minus.com/imwArS2HRDHSm.PNG

Answer (score 1):

```
.front-card .text-input:focus {
    border:1px solid #56b4ef;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using box shadow will help you like this:

```
class{
    box-shadow: horizontal vertical blur-radius spread-radius color;
    box-shadow:2px 0 3px 5px red;
}
```

horizontal (-value will move towards left) (+value on right)
vertical (-value will move upwards) (+value on downwords)
blur-radius: will blur the color you choose around box
spread-radius: will spread color to the chosen distance

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using multiple shadows:

```
input[type="text"]{
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
            0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 
            0 0 0 12px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

i have a demo, it it like the login form for twitter. if you want to view, pls click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/demo/twitter-login-or-signup-form-with-css3.html).